# Minimum value of $A = (x^2 + 1)(y^2 +1)(z^2 +1)$?

Tags: inequality

Given: $\begin{cases}x;y;z \in\Bbb R\\x+y+z=3\end{cases}$

Then what is the minimum value of $A = (x^2 + 1)(y^2 +1)(z^2 +1)$ ?

I start with $AM-GM$

So $A \geq 8xyz$

Then I need to prove $xyz\geq 1$ right?

How to do that and if it's a wrong way, please help me to solve it !!!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118863/discussion-on-question-by-phc-vinh-minimum-value-of-a-x2-1y2-1z2).

Answer (score 3):

Let $A(x,y,z)=(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2)$, defined on $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3{\,\mid\,}x+y+z=3\}$.

Since $\max(|x|,|y|,|z|)\ge 3$ would yield $A > 8$, it follows $A$ has a global minimum value, $a$ say.

Since $(x,y,z)=1$ yields $A=8$, it follows that $a\le 8$.

Suppose $A(x,y,z)=a$.

Without loss of generality, assume $x\le y\le z$.

From $x+y+z=3$, it follows that $z\ge 1$.

We must have $\max(|x|,|y|,|z|)< 3$, hence $z < 3$.

Let $s=x+y$.

From $x+y+z=3$ and $1\le z < 3$, we get $0 < s \le 2$.

Let $u=(1+x^2)(1+y^2)$ and let $v=\left(1+\left({\Large{\frac{s}{2}}}\right)^2\right)^2$.

Replacing $y$ by $s-x$, we get
$$
u-v
=
\Bigl({\small{\frac{1}{16}}}\Bigr)
\!
\left((s-2x)^2+2(4-s^2)\right)
(s-2x)^2
$$
hence $u\ge v$ with equality if and only if $s=2x$.

But we can't have $u > v$, else $A(x,y,z) > A\Bigl({\Large{\frac{s}{2}}},{\Large{\frac{s}{2}}},z\Bigr)$, contrary to $A(x,y,z)=a$.

Thus $u=v$, hence $s=2x$, so $y=x$.

It follows that $a$ is the minimum value of 
$$
f(x)
=
A(x,x,3-2x)
=
(1+x^2)^2\left(1+(3-2x)^2\right)
$$
where $f$ can be restricted to the interval $0\le x\le 1$.

At the endpoints we have $f(0)=10$ and $f(1)=8$.

Identically we have
$$
f'(x)
=
12(2x-1)(1+x^2)(x-1)^2
$$
which on the interval $(0,1)$ has the unique critical point $x={\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$.

Noting that $f\Bigl({\large{\frac{1}{2}}}\Bigr)={\large{\frac{125}{16}}}=7.8125 <  8$, it follows that $a={\large{\frac{125}{16}}}$, with $(x,y,z)=\Bigl({\large{\frac{1}{2}}},{\large{\frac{1}{2}}},2\Bigr)$.

Answer (score 3):

With Lagrange multipliers: consider $f(x,y,z)=(x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)$ and
$$
L(x,y,z,t)=f(x,y,z)-t(x+y+z-3)
$$
Then you have
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}&=2x(y^2+1)(z^2+1)-t \\[1ex]
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}&=2y(x^2+1)(z^2+1)-t \\[1ex]
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}&=2z(x^2+1)(y^2+1)-t
\end{align}
These should vanish together, so we obtain, for instance,
$$
2x(y^2+1)(z^2+1)=2y(x^2+1)(z^2+1)
$$
that yields $xy^2+x=x^2y+y$, hence $xy(x-y)=x-y$. Thus either $xy=1$ or $x=y$. Similarly, $xz=1$ or $x=z$. Thus we have four cases to examine.

The case $x=y$ and $y=z$ yields $x=y=z=1$.

The case $xy=1$ and $xz=1$ yields $y=z$ and so $x=2,y=1/2,z=1/2$.

Since the function $f$ as well as the constraint are symmetric in $x,y,z$, the remaining two cases will provide $x=1/2,y=2,z=1/2$ and $x=1/2,y=1/2,z=2$.

We have $f(1,1,1)=8$ and $f(2,1/2,1/2)=125/16$.

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses a very similar approach to that of egreg, but it may be easier to follow for readers who are comfortable with single-variable differentiation but who aren't yet familiar with partial derivatives.

But first I'll show how we can use finite differences to verify that $(\frac12, \frac12, 2)$ gives a stationary value for $A=\frac{125}{16}$.

Recall that for small $\Delta x$,
$$f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x) + f'(x)\Delta x$$
At a stationary point (a minimum, maximum, or point of inflexion), $f'(x)=0$.

We are given
$$A = (x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)$$
with the constraint
$$x+y+z=3$$
So differentiating,
$$\Delta x +\Delta y +\Delta z = 0$$
For $f(x)=x^2+1, f'(x)=2x$, so
$$A+\Delta A = (x^2+1 + 2x\Delta x)(y^2+1 + 2y\Delta y)(z^2+1 + 2z\Delta z)$$
We want to show that $\Delta A=0$.

Note that when doing arithmetic with these deltas that terms like $\Delta x\Delta y$ and $(\Delta x)^2$ vanish.

Plugging in $(\frac12, \frac12, 2)$,
$$\begin{align}
A+\Delta A = & (\frac54 +\Delta x)(\frac54 +\Delta y)(5 +4\Delta z)\\
= & (5 +4\Delta x)(5 +4\Delta y)(5 + 4\Delta z)/16\\
= & (125 + 100(\Delta x+ \Delta y +\Delta z))/16\\
= & 125/16 = A\\
\end{align}$$
Thus $\Delta A$ is zero, and $A$ is indeed stationary at $(\frac12, \frac12, 2)$.

If we plug in $(1, 1, 1)$, we get
$$8+\Delta A = 8 + 2(\Delta x+ \Delta y +\Delta z)$$
i.e., $\Delta A = 0$, so it's also a stationary point. In fact, it's a local maximum.

---

Now I'll show how to find these points. Let's temporarily treat one of the variables, eg $z$, as if it were a constant value. Geometrically, we want to know how the A function behaves on the $z=k$ plane as $x$ and $y$ vary. So we look at the function
$$B=(x^2+1)(y^2+1)$$
with $A=B(k^2+1)$.
If $A$ is stationary at $(x, y, z=k)$ then $B$ must also be stationary at $(x, y)$.

At $z=k$, we have
$$y=(3-k)-x$$
so $y$ and hence $B$ are simple functions of $x$, and we can use plain single-variable calculus on them. Firstly,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-1$$
Using the product and chain rules,
$$\frac{dB}{dx} = 2x(y^2+1) + 2y(x^2+1)\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dB}{dx} = 2x(y^2+1) - 2y(x^2+1)$$
At a stationary point, $$\frac{dB}{dx}=0$$
so
$$x(y^2+1) = y(x^2+1)$$
and for $x,y \ne 0$,
$$(y+1/y) = (x+1/x)$$
This is a quadratic, with solutions $x=y$ and $x=1/y$. We can see that they're the only solutions by factoring:

$$x(y^2+1) = y(x^2+1)$$
$$xy^2+x - yx^2-y = 0$$
$$xy(y-x) + x-y = 0$$
$$(xy-1)(y-x) = 0$$

So we've established that $B$ is stationary when $x=y$ or $xy=1$. That's true for any given $z=k$, regardless of whether A is also stationary at that point.

By symmetry, we can apply the same argument to a fixed $x$ or $y$ plane, and so we get a stationary point on $A$ when a point $(x,y,z)$ is stationary on all 3 planes simultaneously.

So now we just need to combine each of those solutions:

$x=y$ or $xy=1$,
$x=z$ or $xz=1$,
$y=z$ or $yz=1$

with $x+y+z=3$ to find the stationary points of A. We get either
$$x=y=z=1$$
or
$xy=1$ and $y=z$, and its symmetrical variations.
$$x+y+z=3$$
$$xy+2y^2=3y$$
$$2y^2-3y+1=0$$
$$(y-1)(2y-1)=0$$
So either
$$y=z=1,x=1$$
or
$$y=z=\frac12, x=2$$
and the symmetrical variations thereof.
Thus we end up with these four stationary points:

$(1,1,1),$
$(2,\frac12,\frac12),$
$(\frac12,2,\frac12),$
$(\frac12,\frac12,2)$

---

It would be nice to look at the graph of this function. Of course, that's a little difficult since we aren't four-dimensional. ;) But we can use our constraint $$x+y+z=3$$ to turn it into a viewable 3D function. We eliminate $z$, and use the 3rd axis for $A$.

Here's a graph of
$$A = (x^2+1)(y^2+1)((3-x-y)^2+1)$$
in the region $-0.5 \le x, y \le 3.5$. The function $A$ grows fairly quickly outside that region, and I've sliced off the boring bits above $A=10$ to focus on the interesting region containing the stationary points, which I've marked with coloured dots, red for the maximum, and blue for the minima.

[image: 3DGraph]

Click on the image for an interactive version that you can zoom, rotate, etc.